# How to solve "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException" after converting to .exe

Tags: java, jdbc, exe4j

I developed a todo list project based on JavaFX on IDEA, which can run well on the IDEA.

And the database that I use is Firebird (2.5.9).

When I package the project into a jar, and use 'exe4j' to package the jar into an exe file, and execute it, the following problems arise:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2705)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:82)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

I tries the solution following, but I think it is not completely suitable to my problem.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222789/noclassdeffounderror-java-sql-sqlexception-error-postgres-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com)

And I want that my project can be executable under .exe, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your attentions, I found a solution in a chinese website, it works! URL here:
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/573638445

Comment: If you solved the problem, post and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Comment: Not just for posterity, but also because it will be helpful to other users in the future.

Comment: However you converted to .exe did not include the module java.sql. You need to provide a [mre]. Also, I removed the javafx and firebird2.5 tags, as these are not directly related to those.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening due to the Java Module in JDK 17.
You have to mention the required packages that you want to use in the project in the `module-info.java` file like below.

```java
module org.zoftstack.redpos.lite.redposlite {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    //requires these packages
    requires java.sql;
    requires mysql.connector.j;
    

    ...
}
```